# How to add view created programatically on to relativelayout in xml and below a specific component

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having a RelativLayout in xml file with several components. Now one view created programatically should be added below specific component in activity view.

To be precise, 
XML having RelativeLayout with one LinearLayout.
Programatically created view in java code needs to be added below this LinearLayout.
 How to achieve this requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as always use ViewGroup.addView(View, LayoutParams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, may be help you
I use imageView but you add any other view that you required.

```
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(105, 105);
parms.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

myImage.setLayoutParams(parms);
myImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

view.addView(myImage);
```

Comment: If I am assigning an id for the programaticlly created view , ie view.setId(1000); can we refer the same in xml file for other components? I am getting error in R.java by doing so.

Comment: refer same id declared for LinearLayout in xml.

Answer (score 2):

create another linearlayout in xml below first layout. and add your component in that layout

Answer (score 1):

When you add the new view, you can add a new rule to it

```
View foo = new View();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.your_view);
foo.setLayoutParams(p);
```